# Does Colab stops runtime if it reaches to RAM limit?

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I was using Kaggle notebook for running my NN models but whenever ram usage reaches 13GB it stops the runtime and i have to start all from the beginning. The dataset is huge, almost 450gb so i don't want to shift on colab as i need to import it manually. So i want to know is there any similar problem in colab like kaggle where if it reaches Ram limit it will stop my runtime ?

Or is there any way us Kaggle dataset on colab ?

[Note: I'm using the basic version of Colab]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, if you reach the RAM limit, your process will be killed.
check this link https://www.kaggle.com/code/yuliagm/how-to-work-with-big-datasets-on-16g-ram-dask

Another simplest way is to use Colab Pro+ (The Colab pro not work in this case (13 GB RAM limit).).
Also with this link
https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/general/74235